# Do I need to cover all scenarios in my where clause or is there a better way?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have column data that I'm trying to filter/omit from my search results, but the data is not consistent do to human error or no specific standard. My desired result is to all data that is not similar to green socks.

```
ID  search_col
--- -----------
1   Green Socks
2   green Socks
3   green socks
4   Red Socks
5   Greenscocks
6   greenscocks
7   blue socks
```

In my WHERE clause:

```
Where seacch_col Not like '%Green Socks%' 
   or search_col Not like '%green socks%'
   or search_col Not like '%Green socks%'
```

Comment: wouldn't `WHERE search_col = 'Red Socks'` be better?

Comment: and if the column is case sensitive you can use `LOWER(search_col) = 'red socks'` or use a case insensitive collation

Comment: is your DB running in case sensitive mode?  Also, i think you're looking for `and`, not `or`.  Looking ***for*** a thing is always going to be faster than looking for ***NOT*** a thing (much less not many things). What's a greenscocks? your where clause isn't accounting for that condition

Comment: You could just use `where search_col not like '%reen%'` if you're really concerned about capitals. But the previous comment is correct - filter to red would be better.

Comment: By default, sql server is not case sensitive. If you did not explicitly change the default setting then gReEn SoCkS ==GrEeN sOcKs

Comment: Did you test?  If the collation is case sensitive then all rows will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use a like query combined with lower or upper case:

```
LOWER(search_col) LIKE '%red%socks%'
```

or you can use the soundex function:

soundex(search_col) = soundex('red socks')

However, since soundex produces different values if the length changes (such as if the space in the middle is missing or scocks is written instead of socks as mentioned in your examples, you might want top add a range:

```
soundex(search_col) between soundex('red socks')-3 and soundex('red socks')+3
```

Comment: Why +/- 3 and not another number?

Answer (score 0):

Human-typed differences from a model can be traced with the [Levenshtein algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) approach.

Please take a look [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=51540) for a T-SQL implementation: with it, you could create a stored procedure and use it in your WHERE clause, confronting two strings (your model, and the column value), checking for an integer result which represent a distance that you'll consider apt for your task